# monaco editor registerCodeLensProvider add command arguments

Tags: monaco-editor

```js
var commandId = editor.addCommand(0, function (arguments) {
    // not work
    console.log(arguments)

}, '');

command: {
  id: commandId,
  title: "First Line",
  arguments: ["hello"],
}
```

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-codelens-provider-example

how to pass arguments to the command?

Answer (score 1):

The command arguments are found in the second function parameter.

```js
var commandId = editor.addCommand(0, function (ctx, ...arguments) {
    console.log(arguments) // Print ["hello"]
}, '');

command: {
  id: commandId,
  title: "First Line",
  arguments: ["hello"],
}
```